# Why some countries don't have borderline on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

It's quite useful to display the borderline of a country on Google Maps.

If you click on the country name, the border line will show up, for instance:

**Burma**

[image]

**Afganistan**

[image]

When you click "India", there is no borderline showing up:

**India**

[image]

Is there any way to turn it on for India?

Answer (score 1):

https://fossbytes.com/why-you-cant-highlight-these-countries-in-google-maps/

> To avoid any controversy, and as an indirect sign that a country has conflicted borders, Google doesn’t highlight it when you search its name... A much-known example, in this case, is of India and Pakistan.

If you are still looking for a map of India, perhaps get one from a bookstore? There is also plenty of maps on the Internet, but keeping the fact that [India's borders are being fought over with several countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disputed_territories_of_India), it most likely will differ from each other.

So in short, Google most likely won't be adding a red border for India to avoid controversy.

Comment: Greece has no conflicted borders nor disputed areas, yet it doesn't have a borderline on the maps. I have no personal explanation though.

Comment: True, maybe it's a symptom of just being a country of archipelago? This is also true for the Philippines, which is a country and an archipelago. I checked other archipelagos (from this [wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archipelagos_by_number_of_islands)) and this seems to be generally true.